# Swipe NavigationBar horizontally?

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar

I want to create a `UINavigationBar` like the following:

[image]

I should be able to swipe the icons horizontally. If I swipe to the left I get this:

[image]

I cannot use a swipe gesture recognizer because the swipe event is only fired when the swipe ends. I need to capture each position of the swipe gesture to change the content below the navigation bar appropriately.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you describe is a pan gesture, not a swipe. You can add code that interprets the movement of the pan as if it's a swipe.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by customize your own navigation bar. Like inherit uiview and add swipe gesture in it to handle user's swipe. And you will still have to use UINavigationController but hide its navigation bar. Leave your "customized navigation bar" in the place.
And you can find lots code in github.

Comment: I know how to do this with a swipe gesture recognizer but I need to track the swipe at each step not only at the end.

Comment: Well that is a pan gesture

Answer (score 0):

Hide default navigationbar. Create scrollview with all icons which you want to add in Navigation bar. Add that scrollview in window. So, you can display same in all screens of application.